# Login form created in PHP and MySQL. If else doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

So, I connected a my website to MySQL and I made a login form. This is where the values from the textbox are submitted:

```
<?php
$username = $POST["username"];
$password = $POST["password"];

mysql_connect("localhost","opticon2_rgstr","mario106");
mysql_select_db("opticon2_rgstr");

$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and 
password='$password'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password)
{
echo "Successfully logged in!";
}
else
{
echo "Username or password are incorrect!";
}
?>
```

I added a user called "admin" with the password "admin" in the database, but even if I type in a wrong username and a wrong password it says: "Successfully logged in!"

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure **mysql*-functions**. They have been **deprecated** since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to **[SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you [**don't escape passwords**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/5914775) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I don't understand your code... you select an user in MYSQL where username and password match, then you do the same condition in PHP, weird

Comment: first check the query that is correct !! ... echo the `$result` and run displayed query in phpmysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

You have an error at the very first line. It should be `$_POST` and not `$POST`. Correcting that should fix your code. Secondly,

```
$result = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) as count from users where username='$username' and 
password='$password'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row['count'] > 0) {
    echo "Successfully logged in!";
}
```

Though as I commented above, don't use the deprecated and insecure **mysql*-functions**. They have been **deprecated** since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to **[SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: I think replacing every "mysql" with "mysqli" won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> For now the below code will work for you
>
> Here I have changed your **mysql-function** to **mysqli-function** because mysqli function is depricated since PHP5.5
>
> Your code is not free for sql-injection. So you should see for prepared statements.
>
> You can also use password_hash() or password_verify() function to to ensure more security for password.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","opticon2_rgstr","mario106");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect to server' .mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con, "opticon2_rgstr") or die('Database could not e connected' .mysqli_error($con));


$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password)
{
echo "Successfully logged in!";
}
else
{
echo "Username or password are incorrect!";
}
}
```